# Benefits of splitting a large project into sub projects?

Tags: language-agnostic, layout

I've just been assigned to a java project, which is organized into many small projects (30+).

It took me a while to get the projects to build correctly, because i had to adjust the buildpath for each project.

What are the benefits of splitting a large project into many small ones like this?

Doesn't this increase the maintenance for the projects?

Comment: I think this question belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com rather than SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small project is easier to maintain, debug and test than a large project. If a bug is discovered in the large project it is easier to discover where the bug is if it is divided into sub projects.

Dividing a project into several small projects also makes the code more reusable. If a new project requires one of the smaller projects it just needs to be included.

Integrating small projects into a large one may not be easy but it is worth it once it is done.